# BEM: adding modifier to already existed modifier

Tags: css, less, bem

I'd been confused by simple scenario when I was working with BEM. 
There is a base button in example:

```
.button {
    // styles for button
}
```

and its modifier with more specific styles:

```
.button.button_run {
    // additional styles for this type of button
    // i.e. custom width and height
}
```

One moment I realize that I need modifier for `button_run`, let's name it like `button_run_pressed`:

```
.button_run_pressed {
    // more styles, i.e. darker background color
}
```

The problem is that it's not correct to name the last element as I did above `button_run_pressed` according to BEM conventions. But I need to add "pressed" styles only to "run" button, not for all buttons by writing class like `button_pressed` and mixing modifier `button button_run button_pressed`.

How should I refactor my code to match BEM conventions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to http://getbem.com/naming/, the modifier classes are initiated with two hyphens (--). So a modifier for `.button` should look like

```
.button--modifier { /* ... */ }
```

In your case, I would suggest choosing the following names:

```
.button {}
.button--run {}
.button--run-pressed {}
```

Notice, that I also decoupled the modifier classes from the block class, which is more according to BEM rules. You want to avoid creating classes which depend on others to work.

Since you added `less` as a tag to the post, here's how this could look in less or scss:

```
.button {
    // button styles

    &--run {
        // modified styles
    }

    &--run-pressed {
        // more modifiers
    }
}
```

This would result in the classnames I wrote above

Comment: Ok, thank you. Such distinction makes sense really. And I thought about this way...But do you probably know why modifier should be used with double hyphens? As I answered to @Nguyen Phong Thien I've seen another "rules" on https://en.bem.info/methodology/css/ . Is it obsolete probably?

Comment: It's just a different naming convention, really, nothing else. BEM is just a concept, not an absolute rule on how you need to name your classes. Thus, I can only speculate as to why on  http://getbem.com/naming/ you find the double-hyphen version. Maybe better readability? You can easily distinguish between `block`, `block__element`, `block--modifier` and `block__element--modifier` just by looking at underscores and hyphens.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, the name should be `.block--modifier` or `.button--run`

If you want it only works with both modifier `run` and `press`, you should name it as

`.button.button--run.button--pressed`

Hope this help

Comment: Khm...why it's necessary to name modifiers with double hypens?  As I can see on official BEM site ( https://en.bem.info/methodology/quick-start ) they use single underscore for modifier?

Comment: Oh really, there is a different name styling. Ok it's clear :)